# Ionic Cordova Uber Integration

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, uber-api

Trying to integrate Uber into my Ionic Cordova app were users can request a lift to a location. Having trouble finding the correct documentation for Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps 
[uber integration with phonegap](https://ubertesters.com/knowledge-base/phonegap-sdk/)